# Is it a violation of the Canadian Electrical Code to re-label circuits in my electrical panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, code-compliance, canada

I have an old house, and some of the labels for the circuit breakers are incorrect or extremely vague.

I have mapped out where the breakers actually go. I would like to use a label maker to print labels that I paste over the original descriptions.

Is this a violation of the CEC? I want to avoid problems in the future if the panel is inspected.

Comment: I doubt it.  Seems it would be more against code to have wrong labels than the right ones.  About the same as finding a breaker that is the wrong(too big) for that circuit and replacing with the right size.

Comment: I also doubt it, but you can **certainly** print out a correct mapping (with more space for descriptions, even) and attach it to the wall **next to** the panel.

Comment: In a new install, the electrician would label them.  So, go for it.  I have labeled all of mine.

Comment: I have a video of Suze Orman yelling at someone who said "I'm self-employed, is there any way I can pay my taxes quarterly instead of just at the end of the year?" She was like "That's MANDATORY!"   That for correct breaker markings.  You must correct them

Comment: To label the breakers at my son's house (new build) I simply entered all the circuits & breaker numbers into a table using MS-Word, printed it on some adhesive paper and put it on the inside of the cover.  Inspector was happy with it.   You could enter text saying this is an update and leave the original labeling alone. ...just an idea.

Comment: Heck, you could probably print out a dated copy each time you make an update and keep them all for historical purposes! (Might do this, just for fun, as I start populating my new sub panel with circuits in the addition, then migrate circuits from the old panel to the new...)